# 2 span elements with border bottom line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this setup:

```css
.productList {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70%;
}

.prijzencontainer {
  flex: 1;
}

.price {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.productblock {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}

.product .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product .price {
  float: right;
}

.product-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prijzencontainer">
  <div class="productblock">
    <section class="productList">
      <div class=product-section>
        <div class=product-header>
          <h4>heading1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
          <span class="name">example text</span><span class="price">99 euro</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem lies when the screen gets to small the price piece of the div "product" get under the dashed line like this.

[image]

How can i make this so the dashed line is **always** under the price, so people with smaller devices can get a quick look which services has what cost.

Comment: at some screen width your default font-size/margin/padding will make the content not fit into the small width. You can make your base font-size in html based on vw. And then give all your specifications in rem. This will make it fit more than the px specifications. But still at some screen width it will still not be able to fit. Solution is to change design, the reason we have web and mobile views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `float` you can use flexbox on the `div .product`

```
.product {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can now remove the `margin-left` and `float` from price.

```css
.productList {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70%;
}
.prijzencontainer{
  flex: 1;
}

.productblock{
  margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.product {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.product .name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.price {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.product-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prijzencontainer">
  <div class="productblock">
    <section class="productList">
      <div class=product-section>
        <div class=product-header>
          <h4>heading1</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
          <span class="name">example text</span><span class="price">99 euro</span>
        </div>         
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, i will implement your solution later this day, cheers